# Using a class object inside another class to find the distance between two points

Tags: python, class, object, distance

My beginner Python homework calls for:

"Design a class called Point2D, which represents a point in 2D space, i.e. has 2 coordinates
Should be initializable with two floats, x and y
Should be stringified (**str**) as (x,y) each with 2 digits after the decimal

Design a class called Line2D, which represents a line in 2D space by 2 Point2D objects
Should be initializable with two Point2D objects, A & B
Should have a function to compute its length (use the distance function)
Should be stringified as Points: [A,B], Length: L (where A and B are the string representations of the points  Length should have 2 digits after the decimal

At the bottom of file, use the following to test:

```
A = Point2D(-2,2)
B = Point2D(1,5)

print(A)
print(B)
print(Line2D(A,B))
```

"

I understand the first part, and I created the following:

```
import math

class Point2D: 
    
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return f"({self.x:.2f},{self.y:.2f})"
```

However, I am struggling to figure out how to call a Point2D object into Line2D, so that both A and B retain their coordinates. Here is what I have so far:

```
class Line2D: 
    L = 0

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.A = Point2D(x,y)
        self.B = Point2D(x,y)

    def length(self, A, B):
        L = math.dist(A,B)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"(Points: [self.A,self.B], Length: {L:.2f})"
```

I also don't understand why I get an error saying: NameError: name 'L' is not defined. I defined L inside the class, right? Any help is much appreciated! I am looking to understand the problem, not get an answer for my homework.

Comment: `{self.L:.2f}` try  though L "looks like" a global, which you could "see" from `__str__`, it is not.  It is bound to the class and the instances.  Also, in `length` you also need to specify `self`.  In fact, your original `L=0` might be best put under `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

In class methods you need self.

```
def length(self, A, B):
        self.L = math.dist(A,B)
```

Comment: Awesome! As for the length calculation, I am getting 0.00 because it is subtracting the same coordinates. Do you have any suggestions on to correctly assign A = Point2D(-2,2)
B = Point2D(1,5) within Line2D? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have defined "L" as a static veriable. So you need to access it with class name like this

Access inside class:
`

```
class Line2d:
          L= 9 # Access through class
          
          def length(self, A,B):
                   print (Line2d.L)
```

Access outside class:

```
#Access through an instance
    instance = Line2d()
    print(instance.L)
```

`